# how to create qcm with stopwatch php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem I do not know how to make a quiz with a chronmetre ...
I explain to you what I wish to do:

The quiz is a quiz in the form of multiple choice questions.

The user sees a question taken randomly in the table "proposition", he also sees 4 choices of answers and when he chooses an answer and clicks on send he records the answer in the database and also saves the value of chronometre.
the chronometer works well and the insertion of the answers it worked but the value of chronometer to register in the database always it takes 0.

```
<?php

 require_once('inc/init.inc.php');
 $page = 'Jouer';
 extract($_SESSION['users']);
 $id_loaba=$_GET['id'];
 $limite=1;   
  $pagee=$_GET['page'];
  $debut=($pagee-1)*$limite; 
   $req= $pdo -> query("select * from test,proposition where 
   test.id_loaba=".$id_loaba." and test.id_propo= proposition.id_propo 
   LIMIT $debut,$limite");
  while($data=$req -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo' <form action="" method="post">';
    echo $data['question'].'<br />';
    echo $data['id_propo'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" 
   value="'.$data["rep1"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].'" 
      />'.$data['rep1'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" 
      value="'.$data["rep2"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].'" 
      />'.$data['rep2'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" 
         value="'.$data["rep3"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].'" 
      />'.$data['rep3'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" 
        value="'.$data["rep4"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].'" 
      />'.$data['rep4'].'<br /><br />';
 }
    $nbpage=7; //calcule de nombre de page 

   if ($pagee==1){

     echo '<a href="jouerJeu.php?page=$next&id=$id_loaba"><input 
     type="submit" id="arret" value="Envoyer"> </a>';
    $_SESSION['pageencour']=2;

    }else if ($pagee < 7){

      echo '<a href="jouerJeu.php?page=$next&id=$id_loaba"><input 
     type="submit" id="arret" value="Envoyer"> </a>';
     $next=$pagee+1;
  }
    else{
    echo'<a href="score.php"><input type="submit" id="arret" 
        value="Envoyer"> </a>';
    }

        echo'</form>';
  ?>
        <label><?php echo $lastname?></label></br>

         <span id="mySpan" style="font-size: 80px;">20</span>
        <script 



 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function decrementer() {
        if ( mySpan.innerHTML > 0 ) {
             mySpan.innerHTML-- ;
             setTimeout(decrementer, 1000);
             }
        }
        setTimeout(decrementer, 1000) ;
         var element = document.getElementById('arret');

            element.onclick = function() {
               var chrono=mySpan.innerHTML;
           $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {chrono : chrono},
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                console.log(chrono);
                            }
                        });    
            };
</script>
    <?php

      if(isset($_GET['chrono'])){
      $chrono=$_GET['chrono'];
      }else{
       $chrono=0;
       }


if($_POST){
echo $chrono;
// INSERTION DES INFOS DANS LA BDD :
if(isset($_POST['rep'] ) ){
    $var= $_POST['rep'];
    $pos = strpos($var, '+', 1); 
    $id_quest=substr($var, $pos, strlen($var));
    $rep= substr($var, 0, $pos); 
    $resultat = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO rep_loaba 
    (id_quest,id_joueur,rep,id_loaba,score) VALUES 
    (:id_quest,:id_joueur,:rep, :id_loaba,:score)");

//INT
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_quest', $id_quest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_joueur', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':rep', $rep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_loaba', $id_loaba, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':score', $chrono, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($resultat -> execute()){ 
    $id_insere = $pdo -> lastInsertId();
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    $next=$page+1;
    header('location:jouerJeu.php?page='.$next.'&id='.$id_loaba);

}

else{
    $msg .= '<div class="erreur">Erreur dans la requête !! </div>';
}

}else{
    header('location:jouerJeu.php?page='.$next.'&id='.$id_loaba);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your data type. If the database isn't accepting the value, you might have the wrong datatype for it.